# C# retrieving image from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, image

For a few week I've been working on this application. One of the users wishes was to save and display images. So I've created this opportunity for the user to insert screenshots. However, when I first send the images to the database and retrieve them again, they can't be decoded into images anymore. (Error: Parameter is not valid.) So I checked whether is was the code or something else. I found out, that after converting the image into byte[], I could revert and display that without any trouble. So the problem lays somewhere between writing to the database and getting it back again. I had a look in the database, and noticed that every image started with 0x, even if there was no image to upload. I read something about some databases might add a header, so I guess that's what creates the problem. But now I need to know how to get rid of that header. And if I get rid of that reader, can I still just use the GetValue() function, or do I really need to use GetBytes()? The reason I didn't go for GetBytes in the first place, is that I need to assign a length in start, but that changes from image to image.

Can anyone tell me how to delete that header if that comes with it? I checked the values of the first few bytes, I hoped if I dropped the first two, they represent the 0x and the problem would be solved, but that's not how it works apparently. After that, I tried to upload a picture to the db and retrieve it again, I noticed the length went from 566 to 1335. The empty picture however, despite that the db says it has 0x in it, has a byte[] with a length of 0.

The object bsk will be send to a part of the code, which writes that to the database:

```
 String command = "INSERT INTO " + db.getTabelbsk() + " VALUES ('" + bsk.getEmailapplicant() + "','" + bsk.getCreation().ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "','" + bsk.getCrmQuoteNumber()
            + "','" + bsk.getProjectStage() + "','" + bsk.getRefArticleId() + "','" + bsk.getClassification() + "','" + bsk.getDescription() + "','" +
            bsk.getTrackingnumber() + "','" + bsk.getLastModified().ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "','" + bsk.getStatus() + "','" + bit + "','" + bsk.getScr() + "','" +
            bsk.getBskMail() + "','" + bsk.getEnd12Mail() + "','" + bsk.getEnd3elecMail() + "','" + bsk.getEnd3swMail() + "','" + bsk.getPrmMail() + "','" +
            bsk.getRejectMail() + "','" + bsk.getRejectReason() + "','" + bsk.getCommercialDescription() + "','" + bsk.getTechnicalDescription() + "','" +
            bsk.getValue() + "','" + bsk.getEndhours() + "', '" + bsk.getLockedBy() + "', '";

        command = addImages(command, bsk.getSrcSs()) + "', '" + addImages(command, bsk.getTechnicalDescriptionSs()) + "');";

        sqlcommand(con, command);

    private String addImages(String command, byte[] ba)
    {                  //Adds every byte to the command String
        foreach (byte b in ba)
        {
            command += b;
        }
        return command;
    }

    public SqlDataReader sqlcommand(SqlConnection con, String s)
    {                          //Executes the command
        try
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        catch { }
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = s;
        cmd.Connection = con;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return reader;
    }
```

This part is used to retrieve data from the database:

```
public Bsk returnBsk(Database db, Bsk bsk, SqlConnection con)
    {        //This will retrieve the data from the database
        String table = db.getTabelbsk();
        int trackingnumber = bsk.getTrackingnumber();
        String command = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE trackingNumber = " + trackingnumber;
        SqlDataReader reader = sqlcommand(con, command);

        reader.Read();         //Filling the object with data
        bsk.setEmailapplicant(reader.GetString(0));
        bsk.setCreation(reader.GetDateTime(1));
        bsk.setCrmQuoteNumber(reader.GetString(2));
        bsk.setProjectStage(reader.GetString(3));
        bsk.setRefArticleId(reader.GetString(4));
        bsk.setClassification(reader.GetString(5));
        bsk.setDescription(reader.GetString(6));
        bsk.setLastModified(reader.GetDateTime(8));
        bsk.setStatus((Bsk.Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Bsk.Status), reader.GetString(9)));
        if (reader.GetBoolean(10) == false)
        {
            bsk.setComplexity((Bsk.Complexity.Simple));
        }
        else if (reader.GetBoolean(10) == true)
        {
            bsk.setComplexity((Bsk.Complexity.Complex));
        }
        bsk.setScr(reader.GetString(11));
        bsk.setBskMail(reader.GetString(12));
        bsk.setEnd12Mail(reader.GetString(13));
        bsk.setEnd3elecMail(reader.GetString(14));
        bsk.setEnd3swMail(reader.GetString(15));
        bsk.setPrmMail(reader.GetString(16));
        bsk.setRejectMail(reader.GetString(17));
        bsk.setRejectReason(reader.GetString(18));
        bsk.setCommercialDescription(reader.GetString(19));
        bsk.setTechnicalDescription(reader.GetString(20));
        bsk.setValue(reader.GetInt32(21));
        bsk.setEndhours(reader.GetInt32(22));
        bsk.setLockedBy(reader.GetString(23));
        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(reader.GetValue(24)))
        {
            bsk.setSrcSs((byte[])reader.GetValue(24));
        }
        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(reader.GetValue(25)))
        {
            bsk.setTechnicalDescriptionSs((byte[])reader.GetValue(25));
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
        return bsk;
    }
```

Image to byte[]:

```
Image imageSrc = pb_Src.Image;
byte[] arrSrc;
ImageConverter converterSrc = new ImageConverter();
arrSrc = (byte[])converterSrc.ConvertTo(imageSrc, typeof(byte[]));
bsk.setSrcSs(arrSrc);
```

byte[] to image:

```
byte[] arrSrc = bsk.getSrcSs();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arrSrc);
pb_Src.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);    <-- Error message appears here
```

PS:
I'm aware that [How to display image from database in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031259/how-to-display-image-from-database-in-c-sharp) is related. However, this question never got answered.

Comment: You ask about loading BLOBs from the database and yet you didn't post any relevant code. Please post the code that *adds* the image and the code that reads it. There's nothing wrong with the database itself

Comment: No headers or extra bytes are added when you write or load a BLOB from the database unless *the code* adds them. `0x` ins't a header, is the prefix used to show hex data in SSMS, Visual Studio and most programming languages. All debuggers and editors display binary data using a hex format.

Comment: As for the question that didn't get answered, how could it? The OP never posted the *actual* error, or said *where* the error occured. It could be any of the 30+ lines. This question has the same problem. At the very least post the *relevant* code, not a full dump of the code *and the full exception including the call stack*, not just the messsage. The call stack contains the names of the functions involved and shows *immediatelly* which function caused it.

Comment: About to look at your code but the first thing that comes to mind is [little bobby tables](https://www.xkcd.com/327/). I'd recommend that you use parameters instead of building your SQL by concatenation

Comment: It only says An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll. When I click 'View Datail...' all it shows is this:{"Parameter is not valid."}

Comment: How is the image field in your database defined?

Comment: It is defined as an Image.

Comment: To clarify the point from Fabulous, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks: Use SQL parameters rather than string concatenation to construct queries. Also, `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` and those streams are `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block. Also please read about [mcve], because this question is not 'minimal'. Don't put empty `catch` statements - they will just suppress problems that you ought to know about.